# FirestoreUI orderby and whereEqualTo not working together

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing an issue to fetch data from Firestore using FirestoreUI.

```
//var mQuery = mPostsCollection.orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    val mQuery = mPostsCollection.whereEqualTo("district","West")

    // Init Paging Configuration
    val config = PagingConfig(10,2,false)

    // Init Adapter Configuration
    val options = FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Home>()
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .setQuery(mQuery, config, Home::class.java)
        .build()

    // Instantiate Paging Adapter
    mAdapter = object : FirestorePagingAdapter<Home, HomeViewHolder>(options) {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeViewHolder {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_list_recycle_card, parent, false)
            return HomeViewHolder(view,{ viewDetails ->

            },{ inspectionReport ->

            })
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: HomeViewHolder, position: Int, home: Home) {
            // Bind to ViewHolder
            viewHolder.bind(home)
        }
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        mAdapter.loadStateFlow.collectLatest { loadStates ->

            when (loadStates.refresh) {
                is LoadState.Error -> {
                    // The initial load failed. Call the retry() method
                    // in order to retry the load operation.
                    // ...
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                }
                is LoadState.Loading -> {
                    // The initial Load has begun
                    // ...
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = true
                }

                else -> {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                }
            }

            when (loadStates.append) {

                is LoadState.Error -> {
                    // The additional load failed. Call the retry() method
                    // in order to retry the load operation.
                    // ...
                }
                is LoadState.Loading -> {
                    // The adapter has started to load an additional page
                    // ...
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = true
                }
                is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
                    if (loadStates.append.endOfPaginationReached) {
                        // The adapter has finished loading all of the data set
                        // ...
                        swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                    }
                    if (loadStates.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading) {
                        // The previous load (either initial or additional) completed
                        // ...
                        swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Finally Set the Adapter to RecyclerView
    recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
```

Everything works fine. I am able to fetch Data. All working.

When I modify the Query from

```
val mQuery = mPostsCollection.whereEqualTo("district","West")
```

to

```
val mQuery = mPostsCollection.whereEqualTo("district","West").orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

This above Query returns nothing.

I have indexed `createdAt`

[image]

What could be the possible solution?